# playbackRateMenuButton is not showing on multi-bitrate hls video in videojs

Tags: angular, video.js, http-live-streaming, hls.js, videojs-transcript

playbackRateMenuButton is not showing on multi-bitrate hls video in  videojs

> "video.js": "5.19.2",
>
> "videojs-contrib-hls": "^5.0.0",
>
> "videojs-contrib-quality-levels": "^2.0.4",

when i user older vesion of videojs 5.19.4 and add **video.qualityPickerPlugin()** it got worked. but i cnt used this version in my new angular 5 project